# Ckeditor 5: Large Image copy should resize the image before converting to Base64

Tags: base64, ckeditor5

I am using **ckeditor5** library where, when I am copying an image, it is converted to base64 using **Base64UploadAdapter** plugin. If the image is very big, I want to resize it programmatically to predefined size.

A solution is given in https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/5657, but it uses a library (**browser-image-compression**), which I do not want to use

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve the issue:

**Copy of Base64UploadAdapter:** (from https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/master/packages/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/base64uploadadapter.ts)

```
import ImageResize from './image-resize';

export default class Base64UploadAdapter extends Plugin {
    :
    :
}

class Adapter implements UploadAdapter {
    :
    :
    private imageResize: ImageResize;
    :
    :
    public upload(): Promise<UploadResponse> {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            :
            :
            reader.addEventListener('load', async () => {
                // Logic to resize the image. You have to send the dimensions to which you want to contain the image dimensions
                const base64Image = await this.imageResize.readerOnloadCustomization(reader.result as string, { width: 300, height: 300 });
                resolve({ default: base64Image });
            });
            :
            :
        });
    }
    :
    :
}
```

and in **image-resize.ts**

```
export interface ImageSizeConfig {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

export default class ImageResize {
  private canvasElem: HTMLCanvasElement | null = null;
  private imgObj: HTMLImageElement | null = null;

  async readerOnloadCustomization(imgBase64Data: string, maxImgSize: ImageSizeConfig): Promise<string> {
    try {
      this.canvasElem = document.createElement('canvas');
      this.imgObj = new Image();

      if (this.canvasElem && this.imgObj) {
        this.canvasElem.id = 'Canvas';
        this.imgObj.src = imgBase64Data;

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.imgObj!.onload = resolve;
          this.imgObj!.onerror = reject;
        });

        const imgSize = { width: this.imgObj.width, height: this.imgObj.height };
        const scaledImgSize = await this.scaleImageSize(imgSize, maxImgSize);
        imgBase64Data = await this.resizeImage(this.canvasElem, this.imgObj, imgSize, scaledImgSize);

        this.clearObjects();// Clear objects after processing
        return imgBase64Data;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.clearObjects();// Clear objects after processing
      throw error;
    }
    this.clearObjects();// Clear objects after processing
    return imgBase64Data;
  }

  // Calculate the image dimensions such that it is within given size without effecting the image's aspect ratio
  scaleImageSize(imageSize: ImageSizeConfig, maxImgSize: ImageSizeConfig): Promise<ImageSizeConfig> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let calculatedWidth = imageSize.width;
      let calculatedHeight = imageSize.height;
      if (calculatedWidth > maxImgSize.width) {
        const h2wRatio = parseFloat((imageSize.height / imageSize.width).toPrecision(4));
        calculatedWidth = maxImgSize.width;
        calculatedHeight = Math.round(calculatedWidth * h2wRatio);
      }
      if (calculatedHeight > maxImgSize.height) {
        const w2hRatio = parseFloat((calculatedWidth / calculatedHeight).toPrecision(4));
        calculatedHeight = maxImgSize.height;
        calculatedWidth = Math.round(calculatedHeight * w2hRatio);
      }
      resolve({
        width: calculatedWidth,
        height: calculatedHeight
      });
    });
  }

  // Draw the image into a canvas and resize it to be within the given dimensions and return the base64 data
  resizeImage(
    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement,
    img: HTMLImageElement,
    originalImgSize: ImageSizeConfig,
    calculatedImgSize: ImageSizeConfig
  ): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = calculatedImgSize.width;
      canvas.height = calculatedImgSize.height;
      if (ctx)
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, originalImgSize.width, originalImgSize.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
    });
  }

  private clearObjects(): void {
    // Set objects to null
    this.canvasElem = null;
    this.imgObj = null;
  }
}
```

Only issue is the image is enclosed in ***`<figure class="image">`*** and it has ***`style="aspect-ratio:XXXX"`***. Because of this the images are center aligned and I am not able to re-align them.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**